# Checking if a Sentence String is a Palindrome

Tags: java, boolean, palindrome

I've been asked in class to determine whether a sentence string (ignoring the upper/lower cases, punctuations, and spaces) is a palindrome or not, and return true/false accordingly.

I've already had a look at several of the discussions here relating to palindrome strings, but I still can't seem to figure out what exactly is wrong with my code, especially because it works in some cases but not others.

In class sentence I have prive String mySentence and private int myNumWords. Regarding the static boolean isPalindrome, I was encouraged to try recursion but I thought to try iteration first.

```java
      //Constructor.  Creates sentence from String str.
      //                        Finds the number of words in sentence.
      //Precondition:  Words in str separated by exactly one blank.
       public Sentence( String str )
      { 
         mySentence = str; 
         int count = 0;
         for(int k = 0; k<str.length(); k++)
         {
            if(str.substring(k,k+1).equals(" "))
               count++;
         }
         myNumWords = count + 1;
      }

       public int getNumWords()
      {  
         return myNumWords;  
      }

       public String getSentence()
      {
         return mySentence; 
      }
      //Returns copy of String s with all blanks removed.
      //Postcondition:  Returned string contains just one word.
      private static String removeBlanks( String s )
      {  
          return s.replaceAll(" ", ""); 
      }
      //Returns true if mySentence is a palindrome, false otherwise.
       public boolean isPalindrome()
      {
         boolean palindrome = true;
         String sentence = removeBlanks(mySentence);
         String newsentence = removePunctuation(sentence);

         int indice1 = 0;
         int indice2 = newsentence.length() - 1; 
         while(indice1 < indice2)
         {
            if(newsentence.charAt(indice1)!= newsentence.charAt(indice2))
               palindrome = false;
            indice1++;
            indice2--;
         }
         return palindrome;          
      }
      //Precondition: s has no blanks, no punctuation, and is in lower case.
      //Returns true if s is a palindrome, false otherwise.
      private static boolean isPalindrome( String s, int start, int end )
      {
         boolean palindrome = true;
         String sentence = removeBlanks(s);
         String newsentence = removePunctuation(sentence); 

         int indice1 = 0;
         int indice2 = newsentence.length() - 1; 
         while(indice1 < indice2)
         {
            if(newsentence.charAt(indice1)!= newsentence.charAt(indice2))
               palindrome = false;
            indice1++;
            indice2--;
         }         
         return palindrome;            
      }      
      //Returns copy of String s with all letters in lowercase.
      //Postcondition:  Number of words in returned string equals
      //                        number of words in s.
       private static String lowerCase( String s )
      {  
         return s.toLowerCase(); 
      }

      //Returns copy of String s with all punctuation removed.
      //Postcondition:  Number of words in returned string equals
      //                        number of words in s.
       private static String removePunctuation( String s )
      { 
         return s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
      }
```

For instance, for "A Santa lived as a devil at NASA" as my input, I'm supposed to get "true", but keep returning "false".

Comment: You might want to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for that or look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `new Sentence("A Santa lived as a devil at NASA").isPalindrome()` then you foget do `lowerCase`